# ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString throws exception in PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script as below

[string]$newValue = Get-ConfigurationByType $setting.Value

After this line, the value of $newValue is

```
"http://ST-$($partner.Alias).vardiaforsakring.se/CardPaymentAgreementCallback.aspx"
```

In the loop, I call ExpandString

`foreach ($partner in $partners) 
{
    $partnerSpecificValue =$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($newValue)
}`

It throws exception

```
Exception calling "ExpandString" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\Programs\Drops\Hydra_SE_v1.28\HydraDeploymentFunctions.ps1:342 char:5
+                 $partnerSpecificValue = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($newVal ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
```

But when I try to input hard-code string, it returns expected result without exception

```
$partnerSpecificValue =$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("http://ST-$($partner.Alias).vardiaforsakring.se/CardPaymentAgreementCallback.aspx")
```

The value of $partnerSpecificValue is

```
http://ST-secure.vardiaforsakring.se/CardPaymentAgreementCallback.aspx
```

Does anyone know a workaround to resolve this bug? Thank you very much. I am running PowerShell v4.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: What modules are you using? Is that "spockframework"? Maybe add some details to the question. The error you get, is simply telling you that $newValue is empty.

Comment: Hi Jan,
I just write a script using notepad and run this script by PowerShell. I don't know what is "spockframework"

Comment: When you hard-code, it works because you use double-queted (") string and it will be interpolated before being passed to ExpandString. if you use single quotes (') to pass a string - you will see the same NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround for this bug.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5efc52d2-619c-4063-9a47-bc646c45e882/executioncontextinvokecommandexpandstring-throws-exception-in-powershell-40?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 7):

`ExpandString` is problematic and doesn't work correctly in general case. I use this method instead:

```
function render() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] [string] $str)

    "@`"`n$str`n`"@" | iex
}
```

Example:

```
$x=@{test='test'}
'Hashtable x contains value $($x.test)' | render
```

Comment: Great answer, but could you explain how/why this works?

Comment: it sends HERE DOC string to Invoke-Expression. The string can contain Posh variables.